# Tensorflow image segmentation via linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

Previously I built a network that implemented a binary image segmentation -- foreground & background. I did this by having two classifications. Now instead of a binary classification, I want to do a linear regression of each pixel.

Say there is a 3D surface within the image view, I want to segment the exact middle of that surface with a linear value 10. The edge of the surface will be, let's say, 5. Of course all the voxels in between are within the range 5-10. Then, as the voxels move away from the surface the values quickly go down to zero.

With the binary classification I had an image with 1's in the places of the foreground and an image with 1's in the place of the background -- in other words a classification :) Now I want to have just one ground truth image with values like the following...

[image]

Via this linear regression example, I assumed I could simply change the cost function to a least square function -- `cost = tf.square(y - pred)`. And of course I would change the ground truth.

However, when I do this, my predictions output `NaN`. My last layer is a linear sum of matrix weight values multiplied by the final output. I'm guessing this has something to do with it? I can't make it a `tf.nn.softmax()` function because that would normalize the values between 0 and 1.

So I believe `cost = tf.square(y - pred)` is the source of the issue. I tried this next... `cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - pred))` and that didn't work.

So then I tried this (recommended [here](http://blog.altoros.com/using-linear-regression-in-tensorflow.html)) `cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred - y, 2))/(2 * batch_size)` and that didn't work.

Should I be initializing weights differently? Normalize weights?

Full code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pdb
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.scroll import scroll_data

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 1000000
batch_size = 2
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_input_x = 396 # Input image x-dimension
n_input_y = 396 # Input image y-dimension
n_classes = 1 # Binary classification -- on a surface or not
n_steps = 396
n_hidden = 128
n_output = n_input_y * n_classes

dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input_x * n_input_y], name="ground_truth")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)

# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

def deconv2d(prev_layer, w, b, output_shape, strides):
    # Deconv layer
    deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(prev_layer, w, output_shape=output_shape, strides=strides, padding="VALID")
    deconv = tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, b)
    deconv = tf.nn.relu(deconv)
    return deconv

# Create model
def net(x, cnn_weights, cnn_biases, dropout):
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 396, 396, 1])

    with tf.name_scope("conv1") as scope:
    # Convolution Layer
        conv1 = conv2d(x, cnn_weights['wc1'], cnn_biases['bc1'])
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        #conv1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv1)
        conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    with tf.name_scope("conv2") as scope:
        conv2 = conv2d(conv1, cnn_weights['wc2'], cnn_biases['bc2'])
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        # conv2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv2)
        conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    with tf.name_scope("conv3") as scope:
        conv3 = conv2d(conv2, cnn_weights['wc3'], cnn_biases['bc3'])
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        # conv3 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv3)
        conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)


    temp_batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0] #batch_size shape
    with tf.name_scope("deconv1") as scope:
        output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 99, 99, 64]
        strides = [1,2,2,1]
        # conv4 = deconv2d(conv3, weights['wdc1'], biases['bdc1'], output_shape, strides)
        deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv3, cnn_weights['wdc1'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=strides, padding="SAME")
        deconv = tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, cnn_biases['bdc1'])
        conv4 = tf.nn.relu(deconv)

        # conv4 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv4)

    with tf.name_scope("deconv2") as scope:
        output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 198, 198, 32]
        strides = [1,2,2,1]
        conv5 = deconv2d(conv4, cnn_weights['wdc2'], cnn_biases['bdc2'], output_shape, strides)
        # conv5 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv5)

    with tf.name_scope("deconv3") as scope:
        output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 396, 396, 1]
        #this time don't use ReLu -- since output layer
        conv6 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv5, cnn_weights['wdc3'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="VALID")
        x = tf.nn.bias_add(conv6, cnn_biases['bdc3'])

    # Include dropout
    #conv6 = tf.nn.dropout(conv6, dropout)

    x = tf.reshape(conv6, [-1, n_input_x, n_input_y])

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Permuting batch_size and n_steps
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    # Reshaping to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)

    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input_x])
    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_hidden)
    # This input shape is required by `rnn` function
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)
    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # lstm_cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * 12, state_is_tuple=True)
    # lstm_cell = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.8)
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    # pdb.set_trace()
    output = []
    for i in xrange(396):
        output.append(tf.matmul(outputs[i], lstm_weights[i]) + lstm_biases[i])

    return output


cnn_weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc3' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 128])),

    'wdc1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 64, 128])),

    'wdc2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 32, 64])),

    'wdc3' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 1, 32])),
}

cnn_biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),
    'bdc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bdc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bdc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1])),
}

lstm_weights = {}
lstm_biases = {}

for i in xrange(396):
    lstm_weights[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_output]))
    lstm_biases[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))


# Construct model
# with tf.name_scope("net") as scope:
pred = net(x, cnn_weights, cnn_biases, keep_prob)
# pdb.set_trace()
pred = tf.pack(pred)
pred = tf.transpose(pred, [1,0,2])
pred = tf.reshape(pred, [-1, n_input_x * n_input_y])

with tf.name_scope("opt") as scope:
    # cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y-pred))
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow((pred-y),2)) / (2*batch_size)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
with tf.name_scope("acc") as scope:
    # accuracy is the difference between prediction and ground truth matrices
    correct_pred = tf.equal(0,tf.cast(tf.sub(cost,y), tf.int32))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    summary = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/logdir/', sess.graph) #initialize graph for tensorboard
    step = 1
    # Import data
    data = scroll_data.read_data('/home/kendall/Desktop/')
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        # pdb.set_trace()
        batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, n_input_x, n_input_y))
        batch_y = batch_y.reshape(batch_size, n_input_x * n_input_y)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        step = step + 1
        if step % display_step == 0:
            batch_y = batch_y.reshape(batch_size, n_input_x * n_input_y)
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})


            # Make prediction
            im = Image.open('/home/kendall/Desktop/cropped/temp data0001.tif')
            batch_x = np.array(im)
            batch_x = batch_x.reshape((1, n_input_x, n_input_y))
            batch_x = batch_x.astype(float)
            prediction = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: batch_x})
            prediction = prediction.reshape((1, n_input_x * n_input_y))
            prediction = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
            prediction = prediction.eval()
            prediction = prediction.reshape((n_input_x, n_input_y))

            # my_accuracy = accuracy_custom(temp_arr1,batch_y[0,:,:,0])
            #
            # print "Step = " + str(step) + "  |  Accuracy = " + str(my_accuracy)
            print "Step = " + str(step) + "  |  Accuracy = " + str(acc)

            # csv_file = "CNN-LSTM-reg/CNNLSTMreg-step-" + str(step) + "-accuracy-" + str(my_accuracy) + ".csv"
            csv_file = "CNN-LSTM-reg/CNNLSTMreg-step-" + str(step) + "-accuracy-" + str(acc) + ".csv"
            np.savetxt(csv_file, prediction, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: First, initialize your weights with a standard deviation of `0.1` or `0.01` and see what happens

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot initialized to `0.01` but no luck

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot initialized to `0.1` ... and ... success! thanks, feel free to write an answer :)

Comment: Not sure when this came out in relation to your post: https://prateekvjoshi.com/2016/03/29/understanding-xavier-initialization-in-deep-neural-networks/ but I think it's the go to when doing initialization atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, a good weight initialization is key to the success of a model:

- too high: the model will not learn and may produce NaN values
- too low: the model will learn very very slowly, because the gradient will be too small (see vanishing gradients)

There are good initializations already provided in TensorFlow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#initializers) (as a contribution), feel free to use them.

Comment: I'm interested in looking into those contribs. In the mean time, the network seems to be outputting all 0's, and this is at step 850. Could this be because the stddev is too high?

Comment: There must be something else I can do. Like passing through a softmax, and then doing a linear regression. I think my main issue here is that the output activation function of the LSTM Cell is a ReLu. But ReLu makes sense because it's image processing. Also tried 0.15 -- NaN